# How to add a class to a erb ruby element?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I add a class to this element? I want to style my submit button but I don't seem to find a way to include a class into this.

```
<%= form.submit "Save Item"%>
```

Comment: try `<%= form.submit "Save Item", class: 'my_class' %>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<%= form.submit "Save Item", :class => 'class' %>
```